# Movie about family moving into mysterious house and seeing mystical creatures

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for what I remember is kind of a fantasy movie where a family moves into a mysterious house.

In the front yard there's a circle of mushrooms that the previous owner made to protect the house. The owner has a daughter that lives alone but she can see mystical creatures. The previous owner did research on the creatures in a book which I think some bad creatures wants to take the book for their own advantage.

All I remember is a scene that the family that is living in the house have a daughter and a son (or twins). Both of them went and visited the old lady (a.k.a. the previous owner's daughter). The old lady's bed is surrounded with salt. The daughter can't see any mystical creatures in the scene so she had to wear something on her right eye to see them but after a few scenes they made a nice mystical friend and that friend spit some saliva on the daughter's eyes, making her able to see mystical creatures without a problem.

I think it's a 2000s movie but I just can't remember anything else. Might be an American movie

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What country was it likely from? Are there any **other** plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify this movie about a forest filled with killer trolls and a spell that is needed to free king Troll from a curse](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83588/identify-this-movie-about-a-forest-filled-with-killer-trolls-and-a-spell-that-is)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is easy, [The Spiderwick Chronicles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416236/) for sure.

> Upon moving into the run-down Spiderwick Estate with their mother, twin brothers Jared and Simon Grace, along with their sister Mallory, find themselves pulled into an alternate world full of faeries and other creatures.