# Identify this movie about a forest filled with killer trolls and a spell that is needed to free king Troll from a curse

Tags: identify-this-movie

As much as I don't like trying to ask 'identify this movie' questions (due to the level of detail required in the question) can you guys help me find this movie.

Anyways about 4 years ago I saw a movie on the Film 4 channel about trolls who were killed by salt and stopped by a magic circle. I believe 2 years before I watched it, it was in cinemas so it was pretty (recent) big film and I think it was sponsored by McDonald's at a point because I remember as a kid myself seeing the main character on the McDonald's happy meal cover.

Now I wanted to finish watching this movie because I didn't watch all of it and I was left on a cliff hanger scene but anyway I searched up "Gremlin movie attack", "Magic circle movie" and I even tried "trolls killed by salt movie" but I couldn't find it.

Anyway here is the key information I (think I) know about this movie:

- The main character is a young boy with dark hair at first I thought he was the same person who played Hugo in the movie "Hugo" (Asa Butterfield) because his looks matched the main character but after looking at movies Asa Butterfield features in I couldn't find any other movies other than 'Hugo' and 'The Boy In The Striped Pajamas' I either recognize or have watched before.
- I believe his original dad has died because he has arguments with his parents and I remember a scene where it stated that his original dad is actually alive but is in some other dimension where he lives forever and is guarded by faeries (or something along that line).
- At the start of the movie they go to live in a magical forest as a vacation (to get away from the big city life?) and they soon move into a cabin (previously owned by their original dad) in the woods (Friday the 13th style) and they soon discover a circle around the cabin
- Upon later discovery the circle is a magic circle that protects the cabin from the trolls that live in the woods
- Only the main character can see the trolls I think due to some special skill transferred from his father
- Something triggers the trolls to wake from their slumber and they all of a sudden wants to attack the cabin
- I believe they wanted to attack the cabin because thats where the boy lived and I think he learns how to summon his  dad
- The original father of the main character knows a spell that can free the King Troll from a curse/spell that has weakened him or something.
- The trolls soon discover how to get past the circle and they attack the cabin but the main character all the side characters living in the cabin prepare themselves to fight the trolls using salt because it burns their skin.
- The characters living in the cabin set up loads of traps for the trolls (Home alone style)

The scene I got up to before I stopped watching was a scene where they blew up an oven to damage the trolls with fire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Golbins...not Trolls. :)

I think this might be [***The Spiderwick Chronicles***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0416236/) (2008)

> Jared meets a brownie named Thimbletack (Martin Short), who explains that magical creatures are normally invisible, but can reveal themselves at will. He tells Jared about a **protective circle that Arthur Spiderwick placed around the house** and gives him a stone with a hole through which he can see fairies.
>
> However, a shapeshifting **ogre** named Mulgarath (Nick Nolte) wants the field guide for himself so he can rule over all fairy-kind. He sends his **goblins**, led by Redcap (an uncredited Ron Perlman) the Pompous Goblin General, to obtain it
>
> ..
>
> At this time, the goblins have finished spreading the potion, which successfully breaks the circle when the moon rises. Jared, Simon, Mallory, and Helen arm themselves with steel knives and **home-made tomato sauce/salt bombs** prepared by Simon earlier. The family successfully fend off the attacking goblins, though the house suffers considerable damage in the process. When they are forced into the kitchen by Mulgarath's arrival, **they place all of their bombs into the oven**, detonating them and killing all of the goblins, including Redcap.
>
> <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spiderwick_Chronicles_(film))</sup>

McDonalds Happy Meal toys